# What do the weights in the specaccum function actually do?

Tags: confidence-interval, biostatistics, ecology, interpolation, vegan

I am trying to create a species accumulation curve that accounts for different areas of each sample. For example, samples were obtained from different sized quadrats. I think the weights argument in the specaccum vegan function can be used.

However, I am not sure what this argument actually does. The non-weighted results seem almost identical to the weighted, except for the confidence intervals.

For simplicity, is it acceptable to just run a non-weighted model and then rescale the x-axis to represent the cumulative area sampled? Or is there a better way to account for different areas?

Here is sample code to show the similarities:

```r
# Load in libraries
library("Hmisc") # for making a plot with error bars
library("vegan") # for specaccum function and dune dataset

# Use the dune data as an example
data(dune)

# Make example reproducible
set.seed(13)

# Make species accumulation curve with random method
mod.orig = specaccum(dune, "random")

# Make second species accumulation curve but with weights
# Assign the 20 sites random areas ranging from 1-100 square 
# meters
dune$area = sample(1:100, 20) 

# Run model with weights as the areas
mod.w = specaccum(dune, "random", w = area)

# Model gives NA value for first entry. Remove this value
mod.w.richness = mod.w$richness[-1] # richness
mod.w.sites = mod.w$sites[-1] # sites
mod.w.sd = mod.w$sd[-1] # standard deviation

# Make plot of weighted model in red. Bars represent 95% 
# confidence intervals
errbar(mod.w.sites, mod.w.richness, mod.w.richness - 2*mod.w.sd, 
      mod.w.richness + 2* mod.w.sd, type = "b", col = "red", 
      errbar.col = "red", ylab = "Richness", xlab = "Sites")
# Add the original (non-weighted) results over top in black
plot(mod.orig, add = TRUE)
legend("bottomright", legend = c("Weighted", "Normal"), 
       col = c("red", "black"), lty = 1)
```

Here is what the output looks like. The plots are nearly identical except for the confidence intervals

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`specaccum(..., model="random")` will accumulate sampling units exactly in the same way with weights or without weights. With the same random seed, the sites will be in the same order. Element `perm` in the result object gives the accumulated species number of each random accumulation, and with the same random number seed this accumulated richness is *exactly similar* with and without weights! What is different is how these raw results are summarized. Without weights, the summarized results are direct row means and row SD's of these data. It is a bit more complicated with weights. Firstly, we find the accumulated weights for each permutation (column of `perm`) and then we interpolate the accumulated richness at equally spaced accumulated weights when summarizing the mean and SD. The equally spaced accumulated weights are returned as element `effort`, and this effort can be used as the *x*-axis when plotting the results.

In documentation (see `help(specaccum)`) this is expressed as

> For weighted ‘"random"’ method the effort refers to the
> average effort per site, or sum of weights per number of sites.
> With weighted ‘method = "random"’, the averaged species richness
> is found from linear interpolation of single random permutations.
> Therefore at least the first value (and often several first) have
> ‘NA’ richness, because these values cannot be interpolated in all
> cases but should be extrapolated.  The ‘plot’ function defaults to
> display the results as scaled to sites, but this can be changed
> selecting ‘xvar = "effort"’ (weighted methods)

I would expect the average accumulation be rather similar with and without weights, but variance (or sd) increase when variable weights are used.